# Handson Table - How to save to file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, handsontable

I am trying out Handsontable plugin which looks great, but I am not sure how to implement the save via the getdata function.

Is anyone aware of working examples? I could save to .json or to mysql, but I prefer to keep it simple.

The loading works fine, but I get an error on saving. I have looked around, but there isn't alot of info that I could find.

Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title></title>

  <!--
  Loading Handsontable (full distribution that includes all dependencies apart from jQuery)
  -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="js/jquery.handsontable.full.css">

  <!--
  Loading demo dependencies. They are used here only to enhance the examples on this page
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/samples.css">
  <script src="js/samples.js"></script>
  <script src="js/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="js/highlight/styles/github.css">


</head>

<body>


<div id="container">

  <div class="rowLayout">
    <div class="descLayout">
      <div class="pad">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowLayout">
    <div class="descLayout">
      <div class="pad bottomSpace850">


        <p>Note: this is a mockup..</p>

        <p>
          <button name="load">Load</button>
          <button name="save">Save</button>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="autosave" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> Autosave</label>
        </p>

        <pre id="example1console" class="console">Click "Load" to load data from server</pre>

        <div id="example1"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="codeLayout">
      <div class="pad">
        <script>
          var $container = $("#example1");
          var $console = $("#example1console");
          var $parent = $container.parent();
          var autosaveNotification;
          $container.handsontable({
            startRows: 7,
            startCols: 7,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            contextMenu: true,
            manualColumnResize: true,
            columnSorting: true,
            onChange: function (change, source) {
              if (source === 'loadData') {
                return; //don't save this change
              }
              if ($parent.find('input[name=autosave]').is(':checked')) {
                clearTimeout(autosaveNotification);
                $.ajax({
                  url: "json/save.json",
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: change, //contains changed cells' data
                  complete: function (data) {
                    $console.text('Autosaved (' + change.length + ' cell' + (change.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ')');
                    autosaveNotification = setTimeout(function () {
                      $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
                    }, 1000);
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
          var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');

          $parent.find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: "json/load.json",
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function (res) {
                handsontable.loadData(res.data);
                $console.text('Data loaded');
              }
            });
          });

          $parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: "json/save.json",
              data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              success: function (res) {
                if (res.result === 'ok') {
                  $console.text('Data saved');
                }
                else {
                  $console.text('Save error');
                }
              },
              error: function () {
                $console.text('Save error. POST method is not allowed on GitHub Pages. Run this example on your own server to see the success message.');
              }
            });
          });

          $parent.find('input[name=autosave]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
            }
            else {
              $console.text('Changes will not be autosaved');
            }
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowLayout">
    <div class="descLayout">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Load.json

```
    {
  "data": [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ]
}
```

save.json

```
    {
  "data": [
    ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP/ sqlite seems to be the best solution. My working example is below.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title></title>

  <!--
  Loading Handsontable (full distribution that includes all dependencies apart from jQuery)
  -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="js/jquery.handsontable.full.css">

  <!--
  Loading demo dependencies. They are used here only to enhance the examples on this page
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/samples.css">
  <script src="js/samples.js"></script>
  <script src="js/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="js/highlight/styles/github.css">


</head>

<body>


<div id="container">

  <div class="rowLayout">
    <div class="descLayout">
      <div class="pad">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowLayout">
    <div class="descLayout">
      <div class="pad bottomSpace850">


        <p>Note: this is a mockup..</p>

        <p>
          <button name="load">Load</button>
          <button name="save">Save</button>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="autosave" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> Autosave</label>
        </p>

        <pre id="example1console" class="console">Click "Load" to load data from server</pre>

        <div id="example1"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="codeLayout">
      <div class="pad">
        <script>
          var $container = $("#example1");
          var $console = $("#example1console");
          var $parent = $container.parent();
          var autosaveNotification;
          $container.handsontable({
            startRows: 3,
            startCols: 3,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            contextMenu: true,
            manualColumnResize: true,
            columnSorting: true,
            onChange: function (change, source) {
              if (source === 'loadData') {
                return; //don't save this change
              }
              if ($parent.find('input[name=autosave]').is(':checked')) {
                clearTimeout(autosaveNotification);
                $.ajax({
                  url: "json/save.php",
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: change, //contains changed cells' data
                  complete: function (data) {
                    $console.text('Autosaved (' + change.length + ' cell' + (change.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ')');
                    autosaveNotification = setTimeout(function () {
                      $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
                    }, 1000);
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
          var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');

          $parent.find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: "json/load.php",
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function (res) {
                handsontable.loadData(res.data);
                $console.text('Data loaded');
              }
            });
          });

          $parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: "json/save.json",
              data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              success: function (res) {
                if (res.result === 'ok') {
                  $console.text('Data saved');
                }
                else {
                  $console.text('Save error');
                }
              },
              error: function () {
                $console.text('Save error. POST method is not allowed on GitHub Pages. Run this example on your own server to see the success message.');
              }
            });
          });

          $parent.find('input[name=autosave]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
            }
            else {
              $console.text('Changes will not be autosaved');
            }
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowLayout">
    <div class="descLayout">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SAVE.PHP

```
<?php
/**
Working example
*/

try {
  //open the database
  $db = new PDO('sqlite:cars.sqlite'); //will create the file in current directory. Current directory must be writable

  //create the database if does not exist
   $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ONE TEXT, TWO TEXT, THREE TEXT)");

  $colMap = array(
    0 => 'ONE',
    1 => 'TWO',
    2 => 'THREE',

  );

  if ($_POST['changes']) {
    foreach ($_POST['changes'] as $change) {
      $rowId = $change[0] + 1;
      $colId = $change[1];
      $newVal = $change[3];

      if (!isset($colMap[$colId])) {
        echo "\n spadam";
        continue;
      }

      $select = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM cars WHERE id=? LIMIT 1');
      $select->execute(array(
        $rowId
      ));

      if ($row = $select->fetch()) {
        $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE cars SET `' . $colMap[$colId] . '` = :newVal WHERE id = :id');
      } else {
        $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO cars (id, `' . $colMap[$colId] . '`) VALUES(:id, :newVal)');
      }
      $query->bindValue(':id', $rowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $query->bindValue(':newVal', $newVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->execute();
    }
  } elseif ($_POST['data']) {
    $select = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM cars');
    $select->execute();

    for ($r = 0, $rlen = count($_POST['data']); $r < $rlen; $r++) {
      $rowId = $r + 1;
      for ($c = 0, $clen = count($_POST['data'][$r]); $c < $clen; $c++) {
        if (!isset($colMap[$c])) {
          continue;
        }

        $newVal = $_POST['data'][$r][$c];

        $select = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM cars WHERE id=? LIMIT 1');
        $select->execute(array(
          $rowId
        ));

        if ($row = $select->fetch()) {
          $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE cars SET `' . $colMap[$c] . '` = :newVal WHERE id = :id');
        } else {
          $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO cars (id, `' . $colMap[$c] . '`) VALUES(:id, :newVal)');
        }
        $query->bindValue(':id', $rowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':newVal', $newVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
      }
    }
  }

  $out = array(
    'result' => 'ok'
  );
  echo json_encode($out);

  // close the database connection
  $db = NULL;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```